# Codeception - " Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params:"

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, codeception

first of all, sorry for my poor english.
I have a problem with the test automation.

I am a beginner. I have virtual box instance with my app, where is set a standard address with VirtualBox outside (192.168.56.101). I connect netbeans with this instance, and i have project with my app on this. And the last thing - I'm trying to biuld test automation for it.

Unfortunately, I have a problem,. Test is created, selenium started, PhantomJs also started. I go to the project folder, "codecept run" and... [image]

acceptance.suite config:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
enabled:
- WebDriver
- \Helper\Acceptance
- Db:
dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx'
user: 'root'
password: 'xxx'
dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
populate: true
cleanup: false
reconnect: true
config:
WebDriver:
url: 'http://xxx.app/'
browser: chrome
host: '192.168.56.101'
port: 22
window_size: 'maximize'

env:
phantom:
modules:
config:
- WebDriver:
browser: 'phantomjs'
```

Please help.

Comment: You have a problem connecting to Selenium, so please provide more information how do you start selenium and phantomjs

Comment: I have a this file: "Selenium Standalone Server 3.0.1" from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
Then I run: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar command in git bash, and there is displayed: (...)"Selenium Server is up and running
"

Comment: Phantom: like tihis: https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/10/14/how-to-install-phantomjs/
Then: "phantomjs --webdriver=5555", and i have: (...) "GhostDriver - Main - running on port 5555"
Sorry for double post.

Comment: The default port of Selenium is 4444, you have to change `port: 22` to `port: 4444`

Comment: I changed, still the same issue.

Comment: if Selenium runs on the same VM, change `host: '192.168.56.101'` to `host: localhost`

Comment: Done. It helps. Now I have opened chrome with: "data;" in URL field, and error message: "Using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors". Can I say that selenium is working, and there is issue with my php - test code?

Comment: It looks like an issue with chrome now.

Comment: Have You some advices?