# Codeception/Webdriver: "SocketException: Connection Reset"

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, codeception

I have troubles with codeception unfortunately. There is displayed: http://puu.sh/sVvHW/b9309967a7.jpg

Chrome is opening, but in URL field is "data:,"

Can somebody help me?

Link to my previous question: [Codeception - " Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146554/codeception-curl-error-thrown-for-http-post-to-session-with-params)

Acceptance.suite config:

```
 class_name: AcceptanceTester 
 modules: 
 enabled:
 WebDriver
 \Helper\Acceptance
 Db: dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx' 
  user: 'root' 
  password: 'xxx' 
  dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql' 
  populate:true 
 cleanup: false 
 reconnect: true config: 
 WebDriver: 
 url:'http://xxx.app/' 
browser: chrome  
host: 'localhost'
window_size: 'maximize'
env:  
phantom:  
modules: 
config:
     - WebDriver:  
browser: 'phantomjs'
```

And this is my test:

```
<?php
  $I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
if (! $I->loadSessionSnapshot('login'))
{
$I->amOnPage('/backend/login');
$I->fillField('username', 'admin');
$I->fillField('password', 'admin');
$I->click('Sign me in');
// saving snapshot
$I->saveSessionSnapshot('login');
}
// Go to Item Types Page
$I->amOnPage('backend/inventory/types');
$I->canSee('Infrastructure');
$I->canSee('Device Component');
// Open Iteam Creation Form
 $I->click('Add');
$I->wait(3);
$I->fillField('itemtype[name]', 'Test New Type');
$I->fillField('itemtype[description]', 'Test Type Description');
$I->click('Submit');
$I->wait(3);
$I->see('Test New Type');
$I->see('Test Type Description');
```

Comment: can u try with `127.0.0.1` in place of `localhost`

Comment: Done. Still the same error...

Comment: are you using Codeception with Php framework or what

Comment: I have virtual box instance with my app (app is in PHP), where is set a standard address with VirtualBox outside (192.168.56.101). I connect netbeans with this instance, and i have project with my app on this and I build small acceptance test (I was add my test code to first post).

Comment: This is Codeception + Selenium Webdriver